# Question about dividing simple fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions

I had some exercises and I came upon something that got me confused.

$$\frac{6*10^{w}}{7}$$
Turns out to be $$\frac{6}{7}*\frac{10^{w}}{7}$$
$$\frac{6*10^{w}}{49}$$
On the other hand, for example:$$\frac{12*10^{w}}{14}$$ does NOT equal:
$$\frac{2*6}{2*7}*\frac{10^{w}}{7}$$
$$\frac{6}{7}*\frac{10^{w}}{7}$$
$$\frac{6*10^{w}}{49}$$
Why is that? I'm a bit confused so if I could get cleared up on some rules I've missed, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I downvoted purely for the abuse in your last comment. To answer your question: Your first statement is wrong. You cannot rewrite $(6 \cdot 10^w) / 7$ as $6/7 \cdot 10^w/7$.

Comment: Your operations are not correct.  You can say $\frac {6\cdot 10}{7}  =\frac {6}{7} \cdot 10 = 6\cdot \frac {10}{7}.$  But you should never have a situation where $\frac {6\cdot 10}{7} = \frac {6\cdot 10}{49}$

Comment: You get downvotes because it simply does not show research efforts as a general policy of the forum. However, I myself am ok with all questions.

Comment: You're misunderstanding something.  There is no way that $\frac{6 \cdot 10^w}{7} = \frac{6 \cdot 10^w}{49}$  That would mean $7 = 49$.

Comment: Saul, I simply checked on mathway and that was their result. See here: https://gyazo.com/65ae64f00f15c749421ee13038a3d5e6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{6*10^{w}}{7}$ is **not** equal to $\frac{6}{7}*\frac{10^{w}}{7}$, it is equal to $\frac{6}{1}*\frac{10^{w}}{7}$ or $\frac{6}{7}*\frac{10^{w}}{1}$ though.

It is not like a summation.

Generally, we have:

$\frac{a+b}{c}=\frac ac + \frac bc$

and

$\frac{ab}{c}=\frac a1 * \frac bc=\frac ac * \frac b1$

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the effort. I did use mathway to check and it gave me 49 in the denominator tho.. any idea? Pic: https://gyazo.com/65ae64f00f15c749421ee13038a3d5e6

Comment: @oijioj You are welcome! If you use `divide` command, it again divides for the second time. You can enter `divide` command **again** and see it gives you another division in addition to the divisions earlier.

Comment: Are you certain that that they're not dividing $\frac{6 \cdot 10^w}{7}$ by $7?$  That would give  $\frac{6 \cdot 10^w}{49}$  I tried to do to that link, but I couldn't get it to do anything when I clicked on the button, so I'm not saying that's what it means.  I just saw the word "divide," and thought that might be it.  That would explain the steps.

Comment: Apparently they did, which I don't really understand why they would do so. Thanks you two.

Comment: @saulspatz The link provided was a screenshot of the environment and not the environment itself. Second, as you also said it did divide $\frac{6 \cdot 10^w}{7}$ by another 7 again. I'm saying if you enter the `divide` command in the **environment** you will see it divides the answer again by 7. It works like a calculator.

Comment: Look at the screenshot. Of course $\frac{anything}{7}$ is not equal to $\frac{anything}{49}$. The command divided the answer again.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar Of course!  I should have looked at the address bar.  Sucked in again.

Comment: @saulspatz Never mind dude!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\frac{6*10^{w}}{7} \ne \frac{6}{7}*\frac{10^{w}}{7}$$

Because you have only one $7$ on the left side but two $7$ on the right side.

cross out the extra $7$ and you will not be confused any more.